# Prove or confute the follow proposition

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, ring-homomorphism

I have to prove or confute the follow proposition:

Let $F$ a field and $ f: $$\mathbb Z \rightarrow F$ an homomorphism of rings such that $f(1_\mathbb Z ) =1_F$.

If $f$ isn't injective $\Rightarrow$ $F$ is finite

---

This is my work :

$f$ is an homomorphism of rings $\Rightarrow Ker f $ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z \Rightarrow $ $Ker f = n \mathbb Z $

$n \in \mathbb N$ is uniquely determined and is the characteristic of the field $F$

Such that $f$ is not injective $\Rightarrow Ker f \neq  (0)$ then $n \neq 0$

Now I can't conclude that $F$ is infinite neither that is finite.

If I take $\mathbb Z_2(x)$ I know that is a field infinite with characteristic 2, so I found an infinite field with finite characteristic.

Is it correct? I forgot something important to say?

How can I prove that $\mathbb Z_2 (x) $ is an infinite field?

Answer (score 0):

The field $\Bbb Z_2(x)$ is an infinite field since $1,x,x^2,x^3\ldots\in\Bbb Z_2(x)$. And this proves that the statement is false.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In particular if $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2 (x) $ can you give me an example of this $f $ not injective ?

Comment: Sure:$$f(n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\1&\text{ if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$